# Global.ASA does not work in IIS7.5

Tags: asp-classic, global.asa

I have many projects written in old classic ASP where Global.asa used to work perfectly fine. Since I have installed Windows 7 with IIS7.5, none of my projects are working.

Below is the code for Global.asa

```
<Script language=vbscript runat = server>

Sub Application_OnStart() 

dim objConn, connectionString

set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 

connectionString = "DSN=otsDSN; UID=admin;PWD=;"

objConn.ConnectionTimeout = 5
```

The error comes in this line. Have referred many websites, even IIS.Net but still no luck.

```
objConn.Open connectionString

Application("otsAppConn") = objConn

end Sub
```

The error thrown by IIS is

**error '80004005' 
/ot/admin/page1.asp, line 33** and the Application object which used to carry the connection object string in older family of IIS now showing, **Provider=MSDASQL.1;** instead of complete connection string.

All the projects are listed as Application in IIS7.5 which I could see using the **appcmd list apps**

Appreciate if someone can help on this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve the issue after long troubleshooting in IIS.

1. Converted the DSN connection provider to Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb) instead of Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)
2. Created Connection String in IIS under my website under Custom

   ```
   "/commit:MACHINENAME /section:connectionStrings /+"[connectionString='Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=otmasterdb;',name='otmasterdb',providerName='Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;']"
   ```

   and gave the Connection Name same as the DSN connection
3. Changed the Global.asa connectionString from "DSN=aaa;UID=admin;PWD=;" to "aaa" only by removing the latter portion.
   The new code looks like this:

   ```vbs
   Sub Application_OnStart()
           dim objConn, connectionString
           set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
           connectionString = "otsDSN"

           objConn.ConnectionTimeout = 5
           objConn.Open connectionString

           Application("otsAppConn") = objConn
   end Sub
   ```

Answer (score 0):

see if the information in the provided link helps you get some better debug info. About halfway down there is a setting you can turn on that allowed me to see what was behind the error code when I was trying to run a classic asp in iis 7.5 http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/564/classic-asp-script-error-messages-no-longer-shown-in-web-browser-by-default/.

Comment: thanks for the link however this link only talks about the basic which I have already completed. The problem is coming when I am using the Global.ASA file and especially when making the connection to the DSN.

Instead of Global.ASA, if I make and open the connection object in every file then it works fine.

Comment: ah, I found that by turning on send errors to browser I could get better information than the error '80004005'error. Sorry :(

Comment: Yes that is when your browser will show the error. I looked at the IIS.NET website http://forums.iis.net/p/1146091/1994051.aspx#1994051 for some solution but seems like nothing..I have posted my question there as well..