# Classic ASP + MS Access on Server2008R2 (IIS 7) - read but can't write

Tags: ms-access, iis-7, asp-classic, permissions, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to get my Classic ASP application (works great on Server 2003/IIS 6) working on IIS 7.

I've done a zillion things recommended and finally got it actually pulling up the ASP front page that reads from a database.

But when I try to write to the database, I get errors. "Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80004005' Operation must use an updateable query."

Note: In the application pool for this classic ASP site I created an identity of "app_pool_casemodo" and then gave [website folders], [database folder], windows\temp, inetpub\temp, and windows\serviceprofiles\networkservice\AppData\Local\Temp all modify permissions for that user.

I installed Microsoft's Process Monitor and it is telling me there is an issue with a user account "app_pool_casemodo" having sufficient read/write permissions in relation with this registry key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines. So I used regedit and browsed to that key and made sure that account had plenty of permissions.

Tried using DSN and tried using just file pointing ODBC string and both exhibit read but no write issue.

Image of process monitor screen attached.[image]

Please help. I've been banging my head for many days on this stuff. Feeling like I'm super close to a solution.

Comment: Try adding Create permissions on the folder. Remember, opening an Access file creates an temp file.

Comment: wheres your database located???  inside the wwwroot folder ? . by other hand check my answer to this question maybe can solve your problem :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492872/windows-server-2008-iis7-5-and-connection-to-ms-access-97-database/12499833#12499833

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user IUSR_< MACHINENAME > has permission over the access file?

Comment: Thanks for your help! The only user account I can find on this 2008-R2 box like that is the "IIS_IUSRS" group, which I gave permissions to on all those folders and definitely the MDB file. I remember IUSR_[machinename] back with 2003 Server. Is it hidden on 2008?

Comment: Wrong name, my mistake. No in 2008 there is a new account. Look at this: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-for-security/understanding-built-in-user-and-group-accounts-in-iis

Comment: Thanks! I read the article. Gained deeper understanding. Also: It worked! Thank you! Now to figure out why FSO is not working to create a text file... Do you have any tips on changes to FSO since 2003 Server?